# How to trim off the ".java" from a Java file when running in Bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a few Java tests that I'd like to run by doing `java <test-name>`.  But, all of the files are either `.class` or `.java`.

How do I trim off the end in a Bash script or in the terminal so that the command reads `java <test-name>`?

Comment: FYI this question really has nothing to do with the Java programming language (the fact that your file ends in `.java` really has nothing to do with the question).  I've edited the tags accordingly.

Comment: @ajb, On the contrary, it appears to be `bash` that is irrelevant to the question.  It seems to be about the arguments to the `java` command, and in particular, the one that names the class in which to find the entry-point method.  The arguments accepted by any command are the province of that command.  Given that the question is open to interpretation, however, I leave it to the OP to restore the `java` tag if I have understood correctly.

Comment: Maybe that's possible with bash tricks like @karakfa shows in his answer. But why? Sounds like you are setting yourself up for nasty pitfalls (not to mention any other people who work on the project).

Comment: @Candic3, when running a Java program from the command line or from a script, you *never* include either a `.java` or a `.class` extension in the command.  Instead, you give the fully-qualified name of the class containing the `main()` method you want to start in, something like `java my.tests.Test1`.  The class must have previously been compiled, and you may need to also provide a `-classpath` argument to tell Java where to look for the class file.

Comment: @JohnBollinger No, I think you've gotten it backwards.  You're right that the `java` command controls what arguments it takes.  And it takes an argument without the `java` extension.  But the OP and everyone else already knew that--it wasn't the question.  So your statement that the question is about the arguments to the `java` command is incorrect.  The question is, when you're constructing the java command, how do you strip the `.java` extension off a file name--and that is most certainly a question about `bash` or other shells.

Comment: @ajb, only the OP can say, but my confidence in his level of knowledge is less than yours, in part because he implies that he thinks that `.java` files (as opposed to `.class` files) have any runtime relevance at all.  Anyway, it doesn't matter.  He'll need to ask a new, better formulated question if what he got from this one wasn't what he was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `bash` you can do the following

```
$ file="path/Foo.class"
$ echo "${file%.class}"
path/Foo
```

Comment: or even `echo "${file%.*}"`